# ComboBox not showing contents

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having a little issue with centering the Userform in my screen, and getting a combobox to populate with options. I seem to have one block of code that fixes the placement of the form, but that stops the combobox from showing anything.

```vb
   Me.Top = Application.Top + (Application.UsableHeight / 2) - (Me.Height / 3)
   Me.Left = Application.Left + (Application.UsableWidth / 2) - (Me.Width / 2)

   With Xpriority
    .AddItem "Low"
    .AddItem "Medium"
    .AddItem "High"
    .AddItem "URGENT"
   End With
```

This is all well and good, but when I copy and paste the above into my new document, it sticks to the centre of the left edge of the screen.

```vb
With alDemo
  .StartUpPosition = 0
  .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
  .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
  .Show
```

The above there makes the form perfectly centred, but then the Combobox fails to show any contents.

What I want is the Userform to be centered in the screen, with a populated combobox, rather than being centered with an empty box, or stuck off-center.

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Left` is used for the Excel window. If this is a userform use `Me.Left` to position the `ComboBox`

Comment: This lets me place the userform, which is fine, but the issue is that the ComboBox, in this case named xPriority, doesn't actually have anything in it if the userform's placement is set by anything other than that first block of text